# line up two paragraphs perfectly html/css

Tags: css, html

how do you line up two paragraphs perfectly, meaning they both take up the exact same width when viewing.

js.fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/Q4G9e/

```
<p>Contact me via Email:</p>
<p>Meet @ UTM Office:</p>
```

i want the ending semi-colons to match up vertically. as of now, the second paragraph takes a little more horizontal space.

Comment: use dt, dd and dl tags instead p tag

Comment: @MiguelBorges http://jsfiddle.net/Q4G9e/4/ i just did this, but the bottom dt semi:colin is still slightly to the right vertically compared to the first one

Comment: web and print are not the same. Media, screen, font, browser, OS, ... , there is too many possible configuration that you cannot control. see only what font-family does : http://jsfiddle.net/Q4G9e/6/ ...

Answer (score 0):

You could place the p elements in a div and then align them to the right. That's how I'd do it. And give the second p element some line spacing using CSS. I've added 0.1px, which seemed to do the trick.

```
#alignme{
    text-align: right;
    width:200px;
}
p.adjustSpacing{
    letter-spacing:0.1px;
}
```

I've updated your fiddle (again): http://jsfiddle.net/Q4G9e/5/

Comment: this is a good solution but the left side is not vertically aligned anymore.

Comment: I tried to add a text-align:left, unfortunately that does not vertically align both ends of the paragraphs